# Prove that $P \implies Q \vdash \neg Q \implies\lnot P$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I'm trying to prove $$P \implies Q \vdash \neg Q \implies\lnot P$$
with natural deduction but I'm kind of stuck. I tried going from the conclusion side, which lead me to this:
$$ \frac{\frac{[P] \quad
\bot}{[\neg Q] \qquad
\neg P \qquad(\neg E)}}{\qquad\neg Q\implies \neg P \qquad (\implies E)}
$$

which is where I'm kind of stuck

Comment: Is $$p\implies q\vdash \lnot q\implies \color{red}{\lnot} p$$ what you intended?

Comment: @Shaun yes,. i cleared up the copy paste mistake, mby it makes more sense now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, (1) I don't know of a good way of drawing proof trees in MathJax and (2) there is no universally agreed set of natural deduction rules. Here is a proof presented as a sequence of labelled steps using rules similar to those presented [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction#Introduction_and_elimination).

$$\begin{align*}
1 \quad& P \Rightarrow Q & \quad & \mbox{ASM - left open} \\
2 \quad& \lnot Q && \mbox{ASM - discharged at step 7} \\
3 \quad& P && \mbox{ASM - discharged at step 6} \\
4 \quad& Q && \mbox{1, 3, $\Rightarrow$-E} \\
5 \quad& \bot && \mbox{2, 4, $\lnot$-E} \\
6 \quad& \lnot P && \mbox{3, 5, $\lnot$-I} \\
7 \quad& \lnot Q \Rightarrow \lnot P && \mbox{2,6, $\Rightarrow$-I}
\end{align*}$$

Giving us $1 \vdash 7$, i.e., $P \Rightarrow Q \vdash \lnot Q \Rightarrow \lnot P$.

---

**Here is a proof tree for the above that Graham Kemp has kindly added:**

$$\sf\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\qquad\dfrac{P\to Q\quad{[P]}^2}{Q}{\small{\to}\rm E}\quad\lower{1.5ex}{{[\lnot Q]}^1}}{\bot}{\small\lnot\rm E}}{\lnot P}{\small\lnot\rm I^2}}{\lnot Q\to\lnot P\qquad}{\small{\to}\rm I^1}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp: thanks for adding the proof tree. Drawing the proof tree with \dfrac isn't bad, but I'm used to using the prooftree environment which gives prettier results (and I wanted to leave the OP with some work to do $\ddot{\smile}$). BTW, why did you enclose my align* environment in double dollars?

Comment: It is best practice to delimit all mathjax statements.  They are not always identified up by the system.

Comment: @GrahamKemp: you mean some browsers get it wrong? In any case, I will err on the safe side in future.

Answer (score 0):

(Posted after previous answer was accepted 3 hours ago)

Same proof, but this may be a little more readable format (screenshot from my proof checker):

[image]